# Image in UIButton is not displaying on Build and Run

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, ipad, uibutton

I'm trying to do something really simple that I've done before - display an image in a UIButton. I've done all the steps that I did before, troubleshooted the situation, but have come to no conclusions about what the issue may be. It's just *not displaying.*

Things I've tried:

1. Making it the background image instead of the foreground.
2. Moving the image file outside the "Supporting Files" folder and into the main folder.
3. Defining the button image programmatically.
4. Using a different image (this worked.)

[image: This is where the image is located in my project.]
This is where the image is located in my project.

[image: Here it is under "build phases."]
Here it is under "build phases."

[image: This is the button that contains the image.]
This is the button that contains the image.

[image: This is the image not displaying. Why?]
This is the image not displaying. Why?

Clearly it has something to do with how the image was imported into the project, but I can't troubleshoot beyond what I see now. Does anybody have any other ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: change button type to custom?

Comment: I tried that too. No luck.

Comment: Make button custom and remove background image. Leave that blank - custom buttons are transparent by default

Comment: No such luck. Is it possible that the image wasn't imported into Xcode properly? I right-clicked "Supporting Files," found it in the "images" directory of my project, and went from there.

Comment: Build->Clean. As long as the image appears in the "copy bundle resources" build phase there should be no problems with it. Could you perhaps run somewhere `NSLog(@"%@", [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallGrayCog.png"]);`

Comment: Nada. But I got it. It was an error in how I was exporting the images from Photoshop. Thanks for your help!

Comment: haha my last question was going to be "are you sure it is really a png otherwise pngcrush could screw up". Glad you solved it.